# Micro-usb splitter?

Tags: power-supply

I'm currently building a Qi-compatible receiver for my Raspberry Pi 3, but I still want it to have a port for a regular power supply. Is there any "splitter" out there that plugs into the micro-usb power port on the Raspberry Pi 3 and splits it into two micro-usb ports for power?

Comment: Intersting! I've only ever seen it go the other way (split one connection to provide power to two devices.) I'd recommend you also try https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com

Comment: Connecting two power sources together is tricky and cannot be done safely only with a splitter cable — it would backfeed whichever power source is slightly lower voltage than the other (or shut off) and possibly damage it.